# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'git config --global user.name "firstname lastname"''

Tags: bash, git, rstudio

I'm trying to set up my SSH keys so I can push my program code from RStudio up to a GitLab repository I created.

Running the following command in my RStudio terminal

`$ system('git config --global user.name "firstname lastname"')`

returns the following error:

`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'git config --global user.name "firstname lastname"''`

So I'm guessing RStudio doesn't like the quotation marks, but I've tried every combination of double and single quotations and I still get the `bash: syntax error`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking to a Bash shell that expects shell commands like `git`, not an R repl that expects R expressions like `system(..)`. Drop the `system(..)` and just run the command directly:

```
$ git config --global user.name "firstname lastname"
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem - the  `system(...)` command is supposed to be run in the RStudio Console.